# Is any connector available for to read csv from sftp using apache kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, sftp, apache-kafka-connect

i am checking the possibilities of having one SFTP connector to read data from csv file in a sftp server using apache kafka.

we tried with confluent sftp it is working fine but since it is a licensed version ,is there any sftp connector available as open source?

can anyone suggest a open source sftp connector to use with apache kafka?

Comment: Apache Camel does have good support for multiple communication channel. Follow this documentation https://camel.apache.org/camel-kafka-connector/0.7.x/connectors/camel-ftp-kafka-source-connector.html

Comment: Apache Nifi is open source and provides far more flexibility and config options than Connect